# Regression models with categorical variable: dummy code or convert to factor

Tags: r

I know that this might be a little bit of a silly question, but the main reason that I want to ask is because I have been taught DUMMY CODE! DUMMY CODE! DUMMY CODE! By multiple teachers in multiple classes all using R.

So I did this comparison on the Auto data set in the ISLR package.

```
library(ISLR)
Auto$c3 <- ifelse(Auto$cylinders == 3, 1, 0)
Auto$c4 <- ifelse(Auto$cylinders == 4, 1, 0)
Auto$c5 <- ifelse(Auto$cylinders == 5, 1, 0)
Auto$c6 <- ifelse(Auto$cylinders == 6, 1, 0)
Auto$c8 <- ifelse(Auto$cylinders == 8, 1, 0)
Auto$cylinders <- as.factor(Auto$cylinders)

summary(lm(mpg~displacement + cylinders, data = Auto))
summary(lm(mpg~displacement + c4 + c5 + c6 + c8, data = Auto))

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ displacement + cylinders, data = Auto)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-10.692  -2.694  -0.347   2.157  20.307 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  24.33811    2.25278   10.80  < 2e-16 ***
displacement -0.05225    0.00693   -7.54  3.3e-13 ***
cylinders4   10.67609    2.23296    4.78  2.5e-06 ***
cylinders5   10.60478    3.39198    3.13   0.0019 ** 
cylinders6    7.04473    2.46493    2.86   0.0045 ** 
cylinders8    8.65170    2.92786    2.95   0.0033 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 4.39 on 386 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.687, Adjusted R-squared:  0.683 
F-statistic:  170 on 5 and 386 DF,  p-value: <2e-16

> summary(lm(mpg~displacement + c4 + c5 + c6 + c8, data = Auto))

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ displacement + c4 + c5 + c6 + c8, data = Auto)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-10.692  -2.694  -0.347   2.157  20.307 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  24.33811    2.25278   10.80  < 2e-16 ***
displacement -0.05225    0.00693   -7.54  3.3e-13 ***
c4           10.67609    2.23296    4.78  2.5e-06 ***
c5           10.60478    3.39198    3.13   0.0019 ** 
c6            7.04473    2.46493    2.86   0.0045 ** 
c8            8.65170    2.92786    2.95   0.0033 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 4.39 on 386 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.687, Adjusted R-squared:  0.683 
F-statistic:  170 on 5 and 386 DF,  p-value: <2e-16
```

Both produce the same output, which in my head is not surprising. The thing that does surprise me is the fact that I have been taught to dummy code instead of converting to factor. Is there any analytical, computational, or any reason at all to dummy code over using a factor variable? Using a factor seems so much easier, requires less code, and you don't end up with a bunch of extra variables. The only possible advantage of dummy coding that I can see versus using a factor is that you can select your reference group, which I'm guessing you can probably do with a factor too.

Comment: You can use `relevel` to set the reference level on treatment contrasts and you can use `model.matrix` to check the exact coding that was used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dummy coding can be done easily using `dummies` package.

```r
library(dummies)

#sample data
auto <- tail(ISLR::Auto,10)

#dummy coding
auto_dummyCoded <- cbind(auto, dummy(c("cylinders"), data=auto))
auto_dummyCoded
```

In above dummy coding, two new variables are added (i.e. `cylinders4`, `cylinders6`) as there are two cylinders categories in the sample data.

Now instead of dummy coding let's convert `cylinders` column to "factor" before passing it to `lm`

```
auto$cylinders <- as.factor(auto$cylinders)
fit <- lm(mpg ~ cylinders, data=auto, x=T)
```

Let's print `fit$x`to see how `cylinders` column was coded internally. `R` has converted cylinders column as `cylinders6` and one constant column `intercept` (which is one less than the number of categories available in "cylinders" column along with one extra constant variable. Just an alternative way of dummy coding!)

```
    (Intercept) cylinders6
388           1          0
389           1          1
390           1          0
391           1          0
392           1          0
393           1          0
394           1          0
395           1          0
396           1          0
397           1          0
```

Comment: Ahh, great! I did not realize `lm` did it's own dummy coding internally. That makes sense. I guess it is still surprising to me that no teacher has mentioned this before and relied on dummy coding new variables. Thank you for the explanation.